# ORA-01790 datatype: how to add the ability to use the text in the name, and not just numbers

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, sqldatatypes

I've got next code that I need to understand and make some changes.

To be more specific is the next challenge:
I need to give the possibility to choose not only the **number**, but the **string** for the *name* of the some panel.

Instead of this:

```
select -1 as num from dual union all
```

I should do this(name must contain text instead of number in this case)

```
select 'some_text' as num from dual union all
```

When I make this change, an error occurs as follows:

> PL/SQL: ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding
>   expression

---

Here is a code

REQUEST_SCRIPT:

```
declare
l_data              clob := request_pkg.get_request_data('panel_rza');

l_panel    constant varchar2(2000) := tpl_pkg.get_block(l_data, 'panel');
l_panels            clob;
l_count             integer := 0;
begin
    l_panels := '
    ';

for c in(
    select 9 as num from dual union all
    select -1 as num from dual union all
    select 2 as num from dual union all
    select 4 as num from dual union all
    select 19 as num from dual union all
    select 23 as num from dual union all
    select 18 as num from dual union all
    select 22 as num from dual union all
    select 8 as num from dual union all
    select -3 as num from dual union all
    select 20 as num from dual union all
    select -2 as num from dual union all
    select 24 as num from dual
) loop
    dbms_lob.append(l_panels, replace(l_panel, '{num}', c.num));

    select count(*)
      into l_count
      from dual
     where exists(
        select *
          from v_scheme_element_panel
         where upper(fk_table_name) = upper('panel_rza_' || c.num)
           and upper(type) = 'BLINKER'
           and upper(value) = 'ON'
        );

    if(l_count = 1) then
        tpl_pkg.set_block(l_panels, 'active', tpl_pkg.get_block(l_panel, 'active'));
        tpl_pkg.clear_block(l_panels, 'inactive');
    else
        select count(*)
          into l_count
          from dual
         where exists(
            select *
              from v_scheme_element_panel
             where upper(fk_table_name) = upper('panel_rza_' || c.num)
               and upper(type) = 'BLINKER'
               and upper(value) = 'CLOSED'
            );

        if(l_count = 1) then
            tpl_pkg.set_block(l_panels, 'inactive', tpl_pkg.get_block(l_panel, 'inactive'));
            tpl_pkg.clear_block(l_panels, 'active');
        else
            tpl_pkg.clear_block(l_panels, 'active');
            tpl_pkg.clear_block(l_panels, 'inactive');
        end if;
    end if;
end loop;

:result := '<dialog id="dialog_panel_rza"><title>Выбор Панелей РЗА</title><text><![CDATA[';
dbms_lob.append(:result, l_data);
tpl_pkg.set_block(:result, 'panel', l_panels);

dbms_lob.append(:result, ']]></text></dialog>');
end;
```

REQUEST_CODE:

```
<table>
<!-- BEGIN panel -->
<tr>
<td>
<a href="javascript: request('panel_rza_{num}'); dialog_close('dialog_panel_rza');">Панель управления РЗА № {num}</a>
</td>
<td>
<td  align="right">
<!-- BEGIN active --><img height="24" src="./images/panel/panel_rza_alarm.png"><!-- END active -->
<!-- BEGIN inactive --><img height="24" src="./images/panel/panel_rza_inactive.png"><!-- END inactive -->
</td>
</tr>
<!-- END panel -->
</table>
```

TPL_PKG:

```
function get_block(
    p_text                      clob,
    p_block_name                varchar2
) return clob
is
    l_block_text                clob;
begin
    l_block_text := regexp_substr(p_text, '<!-- BEGIN '||p_block_name||' -->.*<!-- END '||p_block_name||' -->',1,1,'inm');
    l_block_text := replace(l_block_text, '<!-- BEGIN '||p_block_name||' -->');
    l_block_text := replace(l_block_text, '<!-- END '||p_block_name||' -->');

    return l_block_text;
end;
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `to_char` when you have varying datatypes.

```
select to_char(1) from dual
union all
select 'abc' from dual
```

Comment: Wow, it works. All the numbers I translate into the text, as you said

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to mix strings and numbers you have to explicitly convert the numbers into strings, i.e.:

```
select to_char(9) as num from dual union all
select to_char(-1) as num from dual union all
select to_char(2) as num from dual union all
select 'some_text' as num from dual union all
```